# Calling different exports of a module from within Jade files

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me understand the logic of control flow among the 3 engines/technologies.

This is how I understand it:
The request gets routed to the appropriate js module file based on the mount path; which then names and renders a jade file to yield an html page that the browser shows.

Here are my questions:

1. Must there be a 1-to-1 mapping between each module and a corresponding .jade file?
2. Here is what I am trying to do:

   a. Have a module, `classroom.js`, that carries out all the workflow related to a classroom.

   b. The ui/html related that comprise the different screens of that workflow can either be combined or separated in different jade files, depending on how the 3 technologies interact.

Maybe what I want to do is a bad approach.  Please feel free to say it and show me the better way of doing it.
Maybe it is correct, but my understanding of the documentation is wrong.  So, I would appreciate your explanation.

Comment: too less details, is this a client problem? So do you compile the Jade templates to JavaScript? Did you tried anything already? If not, why? If yes, show some of the code, or at least anything how you would do it.